# How do I filter Android App Links to ONLY accept urls that have a particular parameter?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it possible to filter what specific URLs get routed to the android app using the assetlinks.json file?  I would like to do the filter prior to even coming into the app.  I'd like to do it in the assetlinks.json file.  I currently have app links working routing all traffic on our domain, BUT what I really want is something like this:

I only want links that have the specific parameter of quesid=210906192 to open via the app

Example of link:
https://example.com/example/inside.asp?mode=questionnaire&from=list&src=sys&srcid=1&quesid=2109061920&mobile=1

This is my current assetlinks.json file.  I was thinking maybe relation is the piece I'm looking for to only match based on a rule like matching a parameter, but I haven't found any documentation yet on my current scenario.

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.example.mobile",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["03:.......:F4:7E:CB:CD:7A:4C:05"]
  }
}]
```

Thanks for any information you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is very simple .while getting from json you put all link into one arraylist
at that time you should filter one by one by putting the if statement in it like below

```
 if(links.contains("quesid=210906192"){

arraylist.add(links);
```

}

int other case if your link end with specific word then you can put
links.endwith("quesid=210906192")

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm trying to do the filter prior to it even coming into the app.

Comment: I'd like to see if I can somehow filter it in the assetlinks.json file.  That way if it doesn't match the filter in the assetlinks.json it will just open via a web browser and not ever touch the mobile droid code.

Comment: then you just code to filter at api code where you are getting json ,before getting into json compare your data .